# React different representations of same data, parametrize container component render

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, reactjs

Is it an antipattern to return different *representation component elements* from *container* based on some *condition variable* passed to the container?

I have routes for *SummaryPageComponent* and *CustomersPageComponent*. Summary page has a partition which presents chunk of the same data that Customers page shows in more detail. It would be redundant to create two *distinct* container components containing the same data and logic just to pass that data to different representation component. Including logic to representation component isn't an opinion either.

So my question is, would it be acceptable to create a container component which returns either `<CustomersSummaryComponent>` or `<CustomersDetailsComponent>` based on some prop (*summary=true/false* for example) passed to it? That way I could include the Customers domain anywhere in my SAP and parametrize it's presentation the way that fits. Is this advisable or does it make code too hard to maintain?

Answer (score 0):

good thinking it is okay if done using High order components (HOCs) cause you can reuse the logic. eg a YouTube player can show small and large screen without the displaying component not knowing how to do it but just respond to behavior change in screen size, use High order components to abstract the logic: https://github.com/mathieuancelin/react-conditional-render **and**
https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.hebgpvtup

Comment: I did read those links, but the concept of HOC still seems obscure, and seems to induce a lot of noise. What are the benefits of using them over simply passing an conditional prop to container and branch the render by that conditional?

Comment: 1.http://natpryce.com/articles/000814.html and  https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-higher-order-components-over-nested-components-in-ReactJS and https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775 and http://2016.jsday.it/talk/higher-order-components-in-react/

Comment: the following links will give you a clear picture and please check javascript high order  functions